# Call public methods inside child ascx and get result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one UserControl named "ucMain.ascx". This UserControl contain two UserControl, as code:

```
<uc:Address ID="ucAddresses" runat="server" />

<uc:Interests ID="ucSpeciality" runat="server" />
```

I have created a public methods inside ucAddress than return a List. How can ucMain.ascx get my list by public methods?

Comment: Instead of worrying about that, why don't you just create a helper class with common functions that these controls can use ? Your code will be really clean then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. This is exact syntax that I have found and work correctly:

```
UserControlType ucName = (UserControlType)this.FindControl("ControlId");
ucName.PublicMethods();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only call the public methods from the control variable in the code behind of your ucMain so

```
public void someMethod() {
    ucAddresses.publicMethod();
}
```